# javascript returns undefined variable "function name"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing some javascript functions, and when I put them in a separate js file I got this error: Undefined variable: "function name". Functions work fine when I put them inline in the middle of the page. What can cause such a problem? Below you can find an example.

```
function cssColorToHex(colorStr) {

  var hex = '#';

  $.each(colorStr.substring(4).split(','), function(i, str) {
      var h = ($.trim(str.replace(')',''))*1).toString(16);
      hex += (h.length == 1) ? "0" + h : h;
  });

  return hex;
}

function hexToRgb(hex) {

  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
}
```

I put them above in the following function(s):

```
function colors_used() {

  var colors_used = [];

  $('.colorpicker').each(function() {

    var box = $(this).closest('.colorbox');
    var preset_color = $(box).css('background-color');
    preset_color = cssColorToHex(preset_color);....
```

So what I get as an error when I put first two functions in a separate file is this:

```
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: cssColorToHex   Event thread: DOMContentLoaded
```

**UPD:** **FIXED**:
I have swapped an order of functions in js files so that function `function hexToRgb(hex)` goes first and `cssColorToHex(colorStr)` goes second, and it began to work. Weird. Thanks everybody.

Comment: When is the reference js filed loaded?

Comment: It is loaded in the <head> tag if you are talking about that. Strange that other functions from that file work fine

Comment: Is it possible you have a closure containing the function definitions?

Comment: **Grumsh**, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Something like (function(){function cssColorToHex(){...}...})(); Which is known as the module pattern. I might need to create an answer...

Comment: nope, in my js file I try to use it on DOM ready.

Comment: What happens when you're in the console and you type cssColorToHex()?

Comment: basically the same `>>> cssColorToHex()
Unhandled Error: Undefined variable: cssColorToHex `

Comment: Could you share you complete js file in pastebin or something?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. But it doesn't really  matter to which file I am trying to put it to. I have tried to put them into three different.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a js error or the function are not visible in the global scope. If there are no other errors on the page, the new methods are hidden inside a private scope. Not sure how I can help more...

Comment: Please don't post the answer as an update to your question. Post it as an answer and Mark it so that it will be helpful for others here